# twint.token.RefreshTokenException: Could not find the Guest token in HTML

Tags: twitter, twint

I want to use `twint` to get some data from twitter, but I got this error while running:

````
import twint

# Configure
c = twint.Config()
c.Username = "realDonaldTrump"
c.Search = "great"

# Run
twint.run.Search(c)```
 

I get this error: 

twint.token.RefreshTokenException: Could not find the Guest token in HTML


to scrape using twint
````